# User is not authenticated in Django? It shows errors

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I am creating a website so I finshed register page in login page, every details are correct but that is showing please verify your details I mean the else part also I put in a print statement after username and password same details are printing when I typed but not access login.

views.py

```
def sign_in(request):
        
    if request.method == "POST":
        username=request.POST['username']
        password=request.POST['password']
        print(username,password)
        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
            
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            messages.success(request,"you are logged successfully ")
            return redirect("front_page")    
        else:
            messages.error(request,"please verify your details")
            return redirect("sign_in")   
    return render(request,"login.html")

def front_page(request):
    return render(request,"frontpage.html")
```

urls.py

```
 path('log_in',views.sign_in,name="sign_in"),
 path('front_page',views.front_page,name="front_page"),
```

html

```html
 <div class="signup-form">
        <form action="{% url 'sign_in' %}" method="POST">
         {% csrf_token %}
         <h2 class="text-center">Login</h2>
         <p class="text-center">Please fill in this form to login your account!</p>
         <hr>
   
         <div class="form-group">
           <div class="input-group">
             <div class="input-group-prepend">
               <span class="input-group-text">
                 <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
                         </span>
             </div> 
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" required="required">
           </div>
         </div> 
         
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">
                  <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                </span>                    
              </div>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="required">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Login</button>
          </div>
          <div class="text-center text-primary">Dont have a account? <a href="{% url 'register' %}">Create here </a></div>
        </form>
       
    </div>
```

I just want to login with username and password, but it shows please verify your details, but all the details are correct.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`authenticate()` also requires `request` as an argument so it should be:

```py
user = authenticate(request,username=username,password=password)
```

Your view for registering users should be like this:

```py
def register(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    username=request.POST['username']
    password=request.POST['password']
    confirm_password=request.POST['confirm_password']
    
    if password == confirm_password:    
        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            messages.info(request,"user name was taken please choose another one")
            return redirect('register')
        else:
            user1=User.objects.create_user(username=username,password=password)
            user1.is_active = False  
         
            messages.success(request,"you account  was created successfully thank you for choosing us ")
            return redirect("sign_in")  
      
    else:
        messages.info(request,"please verify your passwords")
        return redirect('register')   
else:
    return render(request,'register.html')
```

Comment: i added request in authenticate still shows error brother

Comment: @Asim This is a mistake I saw, then it simply means you details are incorrect, kindly check you details again.

Comment: thank for your suggection bro actually i have this same code in another webpage but this is not working that was i am wondering bro

Comment: @Asim I think you need to hash the password, do you have custom user model or you're simply using default `User` model of Django?

Comment: i didnt create any model brother i just import User in views.py then using but when i create new users that was showing in database but i cant access that was the problem brother already upvoted brother

Comment: `password=request.POST['password']` is a raw, un-hashed password, which django will not store.  When a user logs in, or registers, that raw password is hashed, then stored, so of course it will not match what is sent by the form.  The easiest way to handle this is to create a simple form in a fie forms.py, then you can use `password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')`.  That password will be hashed, and then you can compare it, and it will work. @Asim

Comment: @raphael Maybe it can work now, although I think `authenticate()` doesn't require hash password but `User` model does.

Comment: but brother i didnt use User model its just a html form brother how can i use this on html form ?

Comment: @Asim Try my edited answer, using `make_password()`

Comment: i tried its not working brother

Comment: brother i found one thing my password was showing in email field i dont have email field in this form but that was showing in email field

Comment: @Asim How do you register your users? Show that view in the question by editing.

Comment: i edited brother now i posted my register function

Comment: @Asim You should edit in your question by clicking on edit not in my Answer, I rejected that edit.

Comment: yes sorry i corrected now

Comment: @Asim I edited the answer with correct view, so kindly try that, I mean first register users then try to log in only that users from this view I shared.

Comment: i tried bro its not working

Comment: can you tell how can i avoid this situation in future?

Comment: You were correct, the authenticate function indeed does work with raw passwords.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your intial code,

```py
def sign_in(request):
        
    if request.method == "POST":
        username=request.POST['username']
        password=request.POST['password']
        print(username,password)
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            messages.success(request,"you are logged successfully ")
            return redirect("front_page")    
        else:
            messages.error(request,"please verify your details")
            return redirect("sign_in")   
    return render(request,"login.html")
```

is that you are trying to authenticate a user that has not signed up yet.  This is similar to the code I found in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users), but that code is to **login** users, not to sign them up.

The solution, is then:

```py
def sign_in(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        username=request.POST['username']
        password=request.POST['password']
        user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=username, password=password)
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
        login(request, user)
        return redirect("front_page")

    return render(request,"login.html")
```

Thanks to [Sunderam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17562044/sunderam-dubey) for pointing out my error, the function authenticate() does *indeed* hash the password, so it will take in a raw password.

Comment: now showing this django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username

Comment: Try using get_or_create() as in my edit. The error you show, @Asim is that you're trying to sign up a user that already exists.